# nodemailer error this._socket.write is not a function

Tags: nodemailer

I'm trying to send an email using the nodemailer smtp connection module (https://nodemailer.com/extras/smtp-connection/), but I am getting an error message saying "TypeError: this._socket.write is not a function". I've tried reinstalling nodemailer, but I still get the same issue.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.